# Связать React + PHP

Tags: php, reactjs, nginx, npm, create-react-app

Подскажите, как связать файлы, полученные из create-react-app `npm run build` и файл PHP?

И вообще, как запустить файлы, полученные билдом? Если просто запустить index, показывается пустая страница. Я понимаю, что нужно что-то вроде `npm start`, но что в данной ситуации?

В приложении у меня есть параметры стейта, их я хочу отдавать PHP и получать что-то обратно. Какой самый простой способ всё это сделать, или где можно понятно для новичка об этом прочесть?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> И вообще как запустить файлы полученные билдом?

Нужен веб-сервер: nginx/apache или ещё что-то.

> Если просто запустить index показывается пустая страница, я понимаю
>   что нужно что то вроде npm start, но что в данной ситуации?

`npm start` запускает webpack-dev-server, который годится для разработки, но не для продакшена.

> В приложении у меня есть параметры стейта, их я хочу отдавать PHP и
>   получать что то обратно. Какой самый простой способ все это сделать,
>   или где можно понятно для новичка об этом прочесть?

React - это клиент, php - сервер. Обмениваться они могут запросами, например, с помощью [fetch](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network#using-fetch).