# Взаимодействие React и PHP

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

Подскажите как можно подробнее и понятнее, как можно связать главный файл React со всеи параметрами в стейте и файл бекэнда на php, например с помощью axios.

Есть файл react к примеру

```
 state = {
 //Авторизация
    AuthEmail: '',
    AuthPassword: '',
    AuthAlienPc: '',
}
```

Есть(будет) файл PHP с функциями подключения к DB и записи/чтения.
Как передавать параметры стейта и возвращать что то в React?
Нашел такой пример

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res => {
        const persons = res.data;
        this.setState({ persons });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        { this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

но тоже не совсем понятно куда слать запрос вместо https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users, если все происходит на localhost

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

На `localhost` всё происходит сейчас, пока вы тестируете локально. Я в [прошлом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/880697/15479) про это писал.

Поймите, react - это клиент. Когда человек в браузере зайдёт на сайт, сервер ему отдаст сгенерированный реакт бандл. `localhsot` в нём - это локальная машина клиента.
В то время как `php` скрипты остаются на сервере.

> но тоже не совсем понятно куда слать запрос вместо
>   https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users,

Здесь нужно указывать адрес вашего сервера (домен или ip).